# If R(x) is a random function, is R(x) || R(x') also a random function?

Tags: math, random

If R(x) is a random function,  is R(x) || R(x') also a random function ?

R(x) is random in the true sense.

x is a bit string over 0s and 1s.

x' is complement of x.

|| is the simple concatenation

Edit :

This R(x) is selected randomly from the family of functions {0,1}^k -> {0,1)^k. Once R(x) has been chosen, it gets fixed. Thus Same input will generate same output. Length of R(x) is fixed (k, say 32)

G(x) = R(x) || R(x')

Comment: what is the "true sense" of being random?

Comment: i define a random function as : for any input every possible output string is equally probable

Comment: does this mean that for the same input value can be different output?

Comment: Let me clarify a bit. This R(x) is selected randomly from the family of functions {0,1}^k -> {0,1)^k. Once R(x) has been chosen, it gets fixed. Thus Same input will generate same output. Length of R(x) is fixed (k, say 32)

Comment: @AnkurVj: is it guaranteed that `R(x)` and `R(x')` don't correlate?

Comment: @Vlad:  yes there is no corelation bw R(x) and R(x')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental flaw in the definition that i have given for a random function.

It should be defined as : 
A random function {0,1} ^ k1 -> {0,1}^k2 is a randomly selected function from the family of all possible functions over {0,1} ^k1 -> {0,1} ^k2

Now by this definition, to prove that any function is random, we have to in turn prove that it randomly selects from the family of all such functions.

In our case assuming R(x) : {0,1}^k -> {0,1}^k to be a random function, R(x) randomly selects from the family of functions.

To prove that G(x) = R(x) || R(x') : {0,1}^k -> {0,1}^2k is a random function we need to establish that G(x) indeed selects randomly from the family of functions  over {0,1}^k -> {0,1}^2k, given that R(x) is a random function. However, it is not true as a small counter example will show that G(x) selects from a smaller subset of the family of functions.

Hence G(x) is not random, even though R(x) is

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `R()` is a standard seeded PRNG function, if `R(x)` is random, then `R(x')` is also random, since it is simply an alternate seed to your PRNG. Additionally, `R(x)` + `R(x')` is likewise random, since it would simply be the concatenation of two random strings.

However, it might be possible to attack `x` with the knowledge that `y = R(x) + R(x')`, which, while it would not lower the randomness of the string, might open weaknesses if this random function were used for any security-related purposes.

Comment: Define G(x) = R(x) || R(x') ... For a particular x, say A let G(A) = E1 .... Now what is the probability : 
Now if we know G(A) to be E1, is G(A') still equally probable over the the alphabet ? I think Not.

Comment: That changes the nature of the question. You're now asking if the output of your PRNG will have a discrete uniform distribution, which is unanswerable without knowing the PRNG implementation. The concatenation and complements and the like are unnecessary details, and are just confusing the issue - at a base level, you will always run some value `x` through a function and get some value `y` back, and no matter how you change `x`, we can't answer questions about the nature of `y` without knowing how the function is implemented.

Comment: If `G(x) = R(x) || R(x')`, then `G(x') = R(x') || R(x)`, which means that if `G(A) == "E1"`, then `G(A') == "1E"`. As defined, the passing the complement of a value to `G()` will always result in the same bits being returned, just in a different order. It's still random, but it's easily correlated to the value of `G(A)`. Are you asking if they would be uncorrelated? If so, the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like yes:

Consider the probability `p` of `R(x) || R(x')` being equal any given `y`, let `y = y_1 || y_2`. Then the `p` equals to probability of `R(x) = y_1` times probability of `R(x') = y_2`, since the two cases are independent. We see that it doesn't depend on `y`, so it's the same for every `y`.

---

Edit:
If however the value of `R(x)` uniquely determines the value of `R(x')`, the resulting function is not random! Because the value of `R(x) || R(x')` cannot be arbitrary: the first half of the value determines the second half, so the value cannot be arbitrary. This means that certain values have probability 0.

Thanks to @adamax for pointing this out.

Comment: "the two cases are independent" This is not necessarily true.

Comment: @adamax: from the OP's definition: "for any input every possible output string is equally probable"

Comment: It means that the strings R(x) and R(x') have uniform distribution. But they can be correlated.

Comment: @adamax: maybe you are right, I've asked the OP for the clarification.

Comment: there is no correlation b/w R(x) and R(x')

Comment: is there a flaw in my definition of randomness ... Here my G(x) = R(x) || R(x') does satisfy the definition i have given. However If I know G(x) I can deterministically find G(x') ... Isnt that a fundamental flaw ?

Comment: @AnkurVj: yes, this must be a flaw. Because this way you can't get an arbitrary `y`: the first half strictly determines the second half!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if R(x) is defined as RANDOM in it's true sense, the output will vary a lot with small variations of x. This means that R(x) is completely different and unrelated to the output of R(x'). Also, concentration on two random outputs will produce a random output as well.